# Google Sheets If X in Sheet 1 = Y in sheet 2, display Z from sheet 2 on sheet 1

Tags: excel, function, google-sheets

I have a Google sheet, and in that sheet I have multiple inner sheets, I have ‘overview’ which is an overview sheet which lists various key points of all the inner sheets so that you can see at a glance the information you are after without having to go digging into the inner sheets which has all the detailed information, think of overview as a sheet for a supervisor so they can see all the key information without the need of digging into the sheets.

I have another sheet called ‘courses’ and in there we have a list of courses along with who is in charge of the course and the details related to each course.

What I am needing is for the overview sheet to have something like IF X exists on both overview column 1 and courses column 1 display the value of courses row M on the matched course in overview column 2 at the side of the relevant course.

I also an issue that in overview the courses are arranged alphabetically however on courses they are arranged based on pupils so the courses in sheet 1 and 2 are not in the same order, the list is also constantly expanding as more courses become available so if its at all possible if a course does not have have a tutor I would prefer to leave it blank rather than an error like #ref, I'm not sure how I get a function to factor this in.

I have tired the following with no luck;

```
=INDEX('Courses'!M:M, MATCH(A:A,'Courses'!A:A, 0))
```

**EDIT**

Heres some examples;

```
| Courses | Tutor |
|---------|-------|
| A       | ?     |
| B       | ?     |
| C       | ?     |
| D       | ?     |
```

A course Sheet

```
| Courses | Tutor | Pupils | Start Date | End Data |
|---------|-------|--------|------------|----------|
| A       | Mr X  | 10     | x          | x        |
| D       | Ms Y  | 7      | x          | x        |
| C       | Ms Y  | 5      | x          | x        |
| B       | Ms Y  | 2      | x          | x        |
```

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: please, give on example of how your data looks and how the result might look

Comment: @MaxMakhrov hey that's me added in a table, hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there! Use the formula you listed, but instead of A:A in the first argument of the Match formula, this should point to only one single value, like this:

```
=INDEX('Courses'!M:M, MATCH(A1,'Courses'!A:A, 0))
```

Here's the documentation for MATCH: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en

If you are concerned about blank returning an error, you can wrap that whole thing if an `iferror` formula, like this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Courses'!M:M, MATCH(A1,'Courses'!A:A, 0)),"No match")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the second one worked like a treat.

Answer (score 0):

Possible to make it with ArrayFormula:

```
=arrayformula(iferror(vlookup(A1:A,Courses!A:M,13,0),""))
```